# JLabel text not updating

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to fix this for the last 2 days! I've searched the web everywhere and all the solutions haven't seemed to work. This is my first attempt at using Swing.

Basically, when I call the setText() method, the text of the label updates correctly when I print out .getText(), but It won't show up on the screen?

The method setCard() is where I try and change the text. 
Thank you. Any help would be appreciated!

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private JPanel panel;
private JTextField playerScore;
private JTextField dealerScore;

private JButton dealButton;
private JButton hitButton;
private JButton standButton;

// fields to keep track of what slots are in use
private int playerSlotIndex;
private int dealerSlotIndex;
private JLabel[] pSlot;
private JLabel[] dSlot;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUI frame = new GUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public GUI() {

    playerSlotIndex = 0;
    dealerSlotIndex = 0;
    pSlot = new JLabel[10];
    dSlot = new JLabel[5];

    setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 632, 354);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    dealButton = new JButton("Deal");

    hitButton = new JButton("Hit");
    hitButton.setEnabled(false);

    standButton = new JButton("Stand");
    standButton.setEnabled(false);

    playerScore = new JTextField();
    playerScore.setText("Player: ");
    playerScore.setColumns(10);

    dealerScore = new JTextField();
    dealerScore.setText("Dealer:");
    dealerScore.setColumns(10);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
    GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
    gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 553, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(dealButton)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(hitButton)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(standButton)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 202, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(dealerScore, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(8).addComponent(playerScore, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                            GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addContainerGap()));
    gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING).addGroup(gl_contentPane
            .createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 253, Short.MAX_VALUE).addGap(18)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(dealButton)
                    .addComponent(hitButton).addComponent(standButton)
                    .addComponent(dealerScore, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(playerScore, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))));
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel dSlot1 = new JLabel("");
    dSlot1.setBounds(10, 5, 46, 60);
    panel.add(dSlot1);
    dSlot[0] = dSlot1;

    JLabel dSlot2 = new JLabel("");
    dSlot2.setBounds(66, 5, 46, 60);
    panel.add(dSlot2);
    dSlot[1] = dSlot2;

    JLabel dSlot3 = new JLabel("");
    dSlot3.setBounds(122, 5, 46, 60);
    panel.add(dSlot3);
    dSlot[2] = dSlot3;

    JLabel dSlot4 = new JLabel("");
    dSlot4.setBounds(178, 5, 46, 60);
    panel.add(dSlot4);
    dSlot[3] = dSlot4;

    JLabel dSlot5 = new JLabel("");
    dSlot5.setBounds(234, 5, 46, 60);
    panel.add(dSlot5);
    dSlot[4] = dSlot5;

    JLabel pSlot1 = new JLabel("");
    pSlot1.setBounds(10, 143, 46, 60);
    panel.add(pSlot1);
    pSlot[0] = pSlot1;

    JLabel pSlot2 = new JLabel("");
    pSlot2.setBounds(66, 143, 46, 60);
    panel.add(pSlot2);
    pSlot[1] = pSlot2;

    JLabel pSlot3 = new JLabel("");
    pSlot3.setBounds(122, 143, 46, 60);
    panel.add(pSlot3);
    pSlot[2] = pSlot3;

    JLabel pSlot4 = new JLabel("");
    pSlot4.setBounds(178, 143, 46, 60);
    panel.add(pSlot4);
    pSlot[3] = pSlot4;

    JLabel pSlot5 = new JLabel("");
    pSlot5.setBounds(234, 143, 46, 60);
    panel.add(pSlot5);
    pSlot[4] = pSlot5;

    JLabel pSlot6 = new JLabel("");
    pSlot6.setBounds(290, 143, 46, 60);
    panel.add(pSlot6);
    pSlot[5] = pSlot6;

    JLabel pSlot7 = new JLabel("");
    pSlot7.setBounds(346, 143, 46, 60);
    panel.add(pSlot7);
    pSlot[6] = pSlot7;

    JLabel pSlot8 = new JLabel("");
    pSlot8.setBounds(402, 143, 46, 60);
    panel.add(pSlot8);
    pSlot[7] = pSlot8;

    JLabel pSlot9 = new JLabel("");
    pSlot9.setBounds(458, 143, 46, 60);
    panel.add(pSlot9);
    pSlot[8] = pSlot9;

    JLabel pSlot10 = new JLabel("");
    pSlot10.setBounds(514, 143, 46, 60);
    panel.add(pSlot10);
    pSlot[9] = pSlot10;

    contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);

    dealButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == dealButton) {
                try {
                    Game game = new Game();
                } catch (InvalidMoveException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                dealEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });

}

public void setCard(Player p, Card c) throws InvalidMoveException {

    if (p.getName().equals("player")) {

        pSlot[playerSlotIndex].setText(c.toString());

        if (playerSlotIndex < pSlot.length) {
            playerSlotIndex++;

        }
    }
}

public void hitEnabled(boolean b) {
    hitButton.setEnabled(b);
}

public void dealEnabled(boolean b) {
    dealButton.setEnabled(b);
}

public void standEnabled(boolean b) {
    standButton.setEnabled(b);
}
```

*EDIT* - the class where i call setCard()

```
private Deck deck;
private Player player;
private Player dealer;

public Game() throws InvalidMoveException{
    this.deck = new Deck(1,true);
    player = new Player("player");
    dealer = new Player("dealer");
    initialDeal();
}

public void initialDeal() throws InvalidMoveException{

    //deal players first 2 cards
    dealCard(player, deck.dealNextCard());
    dealCard(player, deck.dealNextCard());

    //deals dealers first 2 cards
    dealCard(dealer, deck.dealNextCard());
    dealCard(dealer, deck.dealNextCard());

}

public void dealCard(Player p, Card c) throws InvalidMoveException{
    super.setCard(p, c);
    p.addCard(c);
}
```

}

Comment: `"The method setCard() is where i try and change the text..."` -- and where is this method called, and what calls this method?

Comment: its called in another class. the method does work (when i add a print statement, it prints out the correct text) it just doesnt get displayed on the panel

Comment: So how are we to help you debug your problem when you haven't shown where or how this is being called? For all we know, this other class could be creating a ***new*** GUI object, a completely distinct and separate object from the one that's being displayed, and so you could be calling `setCard()` on the wrong object, again, a non-displayed GUI object. Please improve your question. Consider creating a valid [mcve] (please read the link).

Comment: Helen, I know this isn't your question; but are you aware that Swing has been obsolete for a few years now?  It's now been replaced by Java FX.  If you're going to start learning a new technology for Java GUI work, I'd strongly recommend starting with Java FX.

Comment: I would like to learn Java FX but this project is for a university assignment and they want us to use swing

Comment: Does  `Game` extend `GUI`?

Comment: Ah, you're misusing inheritance. Don't do this. You're doing the same mistake that I stated above, but in a much more subversive way -- calling `setCard()` on the wrong instance. It will only work if you call it on the **visualized** GUI object.

Comment: You're also leaving out important bits of your code, including the signature for the Game class where you show that it does in fact (incorrectly) extend GUI. Again, please read and learn the [mcve] link to learn how to post much better code when asking questions.

Comment: What Hovercraft is saying is that your GUI object creates a new Game object.  But each Game object is also a GUI, which it probably shouldn't be.  Your Game object is calling setCard on itself, instead of on the GUI object that created it.

Comment: And re the whole Java FX vs Swing thing - I understand that it's not your fault; but I just love it when universities teach obsolete technology.  It means that we get fresh graduates in the workforce who immediately need retraining.  May I suggest that you approach your university, and ask them if they would mind teaching current technology instead of something that's obsolete?  It will make you more employable and more useful in the workplace, once you finish your degree.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: that would be fighting a losing battle since so many colleges do this.

Comment: What would the visualized object be? Since the deal class etends the GUI isnt that the correct instance to call on? Sorry in new to this.

Comment: Now i understand! Thank you. Ill try fix it now

Comment: Roughly speaking, your code (1) Creates a GUI and shows it on the screen.  (2) Creates a Game that's also a GUI, but doesn't show it.  (3) Calls the setCard method on the GUI that was created at step (2).  It needed to be the GUI that was created at step (1).

Comment: No, you will want to review some basic lessons on objects. The visualized GUI is the one created in the main method, where you call `new GUI()`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels A marathon must be run one step at a time.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: [fingers in the dyke](http://dragonflycap.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Fingers-in-a-dyke.jpg)